# TP LINK TL-WN722N Driver Problem

Tags: make

so I'm fairly new to Lubuntu. I want to install new drivers for my TP LINK TL-WN722N wireless adapter. I get this error when I execute the make command.

```
    diqn@didu:/media/diqn/nothing/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.3.0.8_13968.20150417$ sudo make
"******************************************"
"NO SKRC,we will use default KSRC"
"******************************************"
make ARCH=i386 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.15.0-106-generic/build M=/media/diqn/nothing/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.3.0.8_13968.20150417  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-106-generic'
"******************************************"
"NO SKRC,we will use default KSRC"
"******************************************"
  CC [M]  /media/diqn/nothing/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.3.0.8_13968.20150417/core/rtw_cmd.o
/bin/sh: 1: gcc: not found
scripts/Makefile.build:330: recipe for target '/media/diqn/nothing/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.3.0.8_13968.20150417/core/rtw_cmd.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/media/diqn/nothing/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.3.0.8_13968.20150417/core/rtw_cmd.o] Error 127
Makefile:1577: recipe for target '_module_/media/diqn/nothing/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.3.0.8_13968.20150417' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/media/diqn/nothing/rtl8188EUS_linux_v4.3.0.8_13968.20150417] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-106-generic'
Makefile:1367: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

How do I fix this? I updated and upgraded my OS.

Comment: where did you get these drivers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> gcc: not found

This indicates that `gcc` is not installed... to install that, do `sudo apt install build-essential` (essential tools for building packages).

Where did you get the driver anyway? As the fellow owner of a TL-WN722N, this repository worked for me: https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu

Building the driver will also need the Linux kernel headers, so `sudo apt install linux-headers-generic`.

Comment: TP Link's page. There is a dropdown menu for a version. Here is a link - https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/download/tl-wn722n/#Driver My hardware version is V3. I will try this solution tomorrow and give some feedback. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I suspect that this circa-2015 driver won't compile corretly for your more modern 4.15-xx kernel. If it does not, follow @ashvatthama 's excellent advice and try rtlwifi_new.

Comment: Tried to install the repository. Did not work. Directory .git does not exist indicating that you downloaded the source as a zip file. Only the 'git clone' method is now supported.
Makefile:152: recipe for target 'test' failed
make: *** [test] Error 1

Comment: Well, the error is plain. You seem to have downloaded it as a zip file, which they don't support. You must clone the repository with `git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu.git` (install `git` if needed)